# Placing axis labels inside graticule on data frame of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-9.3, grids-graticules

I'd like to add a graticule in DMS to my map in ArcMap 9.3, having tick marks and label axes inside the main figure/frame (similar to the below map). Although setting it for tick marks is very easy, I couldn't find a solution for the labels. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you use a negative Label Offset on the Labels tab of the Reference System Properties, it will move them where you want:

[image]

Comment: A) In his example labels are on left axis only b) just try it

Comment: Look at 57 30 W along the top.

Comment: I just tested at 10.3.1 and you are right about b) - I had overlooked that Label Offset type in, and was thinking you had gone to Additional Properties to set the text symbol offset there.

Comment: Great. Hopefully it will work in 9.3, might not be a case though,  i have bad memories about 9